# Failed EAS Build: production when running gradlew on Android Play Store build

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

Excuse me, I am trying to build my react-native app with expo: "eas build --platform android", but it logs some errors. I'm using EXPO SDK 46. Please help.

And here's my dependencies:

```
`"dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-react-native": "^0.5.1",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/judson": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/noto-sans": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/open-sans": "^0.1.0",
    "@nlazzos/react-native-skeleton": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-analytics": "^1.0.16",
    "expo-application": "~4.2.2",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.4.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-crypto": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.4",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-network": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-screen-capture": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-store-review": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1275.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-cn-richtext-editor": "^1.0.40",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-copilot": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fetch-polyfill": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-slider-banner": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.3",
    "react-native-otp-textinput": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-generator": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-scroll-into-view": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.22",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "rn-swipe-button": "^1.2.8",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1"
  }`
```

Here's the log, I upload into my GoogleDrive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zRyEk0u5je6pzaHuSYrFIUbDLpH5yc3i/view?usp=sharing

I'm expecting Android Play Store build success. I've been trying to finish this for about 3 months

Comment: Did you try what was suggested in the `stderr` part of your log? Specifically, these two tasks seem to have failed: `:expo-updates:createReleaseExpoManifest`, `:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` .

Comment: well, I don't know how to do the suggestion and I don't know the problem is. I've tried deleted the expo-update but it is the important thing. My app getting error